# Find documents in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two separated collections one for products and one for categories
My product schema:

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String, required: true },
  catalogNumber: { type: Number, required: true },
  barCode: { type: Number, required: true },
  quantity: { type: String, required: true },
  transportPackages: { type: String, required: true },
  category: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "ProductCategory",
    required: true,
  },
  translation: {
    en: {
      name: { type: String, required: true },
      description: { type: String, required: true },
    },
  },
});
```

My category schema:

```
const productCategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  path: { type: String, require: true },
  translate: {
    en: {
      name: { type: String, required: true },
    },
  },
});
```

So I want to query the products based on search by category. I also do populate for the category in product's pre hook. Here is my code right now that doesn't work only with nested fields.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to find by category which is set in the products, you must make sure that when you create a product it is assigned a category then you can use:

```
Product.find({category: req.body.category})
  .populate([{ path: 'category'}])
  .exec((error, populatedProduct) => { 
      return res.send(populatedProduct)
  })
```

which will return the category information along with the product.

Comment: As I mentioned I'm populating category in my pre find hook in products schema:

productSchema.pre(/^find/, function (next) {
  this.populate({
    path: "category",
  });

  next();
});